# Looking for a simple way to place a box of colour behind a table

Tags: css, html-table, outlook, html-email

I have a table set up for an email form and I want to create a box behind it that's a few pixels wider so I can colour it white.

It works fine if I place the table in a `<div>` and style it but I'm sending the email form to Outlook and in Outlook the div doesn't work.

What's the simplest way to place a box of colour behind everything else and center it?

Comment: Post an example of the html that isn't working in Outlook.

Comment: Do note that most email clients apply their own CSS rules -- you should make sure that your styling is inline ( eg `<div style="border: 2px solid black">` ) so that it applies.

Comment: maybe place the table in another table with background white and one row and cell with cellpadding? Should work in all mailclients

Comment: @hexblot either with inline css it's still not showing up in Outlook

Comment: @Adsy need an example of the code then, or try ending your inline styles with `!important` (eg `<div style="background: black !important;">` -- messy business but should work.

Comment: The comment by @JeroenW is the only solution that will work in most email clients.

Comment: @JeroenW Yes! this did the job, I tried nesting a table before but I did it wrong. Got it working perfectly now, thanks fella's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#000" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <table width="600" bgcolor="#fff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <!-- Email content -->
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```